# pass multidimensional array to JSON data to fill chart variable

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to plot my array to chart.

```
arr_amount = [["0-200", "200-400", ">400"]];
arr_proname = [["HSD", "Unlead"]];
arr_salecount = [[10,20,15],[9,16,25]];
```

it is working ok if I pass the particular index of arr_amount and arr_salecount.

```
var chartdata = {
    labels: arr_amount[0],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: arr_proname[0],
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 0.75)",
            borderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
            data: arr_salecount[0]
        }
    ]
};
```

Now i am trying to pass all rows of array, but i am not getting exact how could i have to pass whole array using like arr_salecount[i] rather arr_salecount[0].

Example:

data: takes data only like [10,20,15]
but what if i wanted to pass data like
arr_salecount[i] mean --> [[10,20,15],[9,16,25]]

Edit: Change Array from [{},{}] to [[],[]].

Comment: This isn't valid json: `[{"0-200", "200-400", ">400"}]`. It should either be an array: `["0-200", "200-400", ">400"]` or an object (with key: value) `{"someKey": "0-200", "someOtherKey": "200-400", "aThirdKey": ">400"}`. `[]` are for arrays and `{}` are for objects.

Comment: Consider describing how are you planning to use the chartdata variable

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes as you said that is not valid but as i new to JSON i just wanted to pass  multidimensional javascript array rather 1D. show by doing [{},{}], i am just showing multidimensional array.

Comment: I explained what was wrong with it. Just do `[["xxx", "xxx", ...]]` and you have a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Find difficulties as totally new to JSON but at last solved as below.

```
var chartdata = {
    labels: arr_amount[0],
    datasets:[]
};
for(var i=0;i<arr_proname.length;i++){
    var datasets1=[];
    datasets1["label"]= arr_proname[i];
    datasets1["fill"]= false;
    datasets1["lineTension"]= 0.1;
    datasets1["backgroundColor"]= arr_gradecolor[i];
    datasets1["pointHoverBackgroundColor"]= "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)";
    datasets1["pointHoverBorderColor"]= "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)";                                 
    datasets1["data"]= arr_salecount[i];
    chartdata.datasets.push(datasets1);
}
```